# GCP "12 Months 300$ Free Trial" removed due to billing account change?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, trial

I registered few months ago on the google cloud platform for the "12 months 300$ trial" to test the possibilities of the cloud.

On top of gcp there was always a banner saying how many days and how many $ left for trial period.

When the first billing with 0$ came in, I got a lot of trouble with our accountant because the bill wasn't set on our company but personal/private.

After a lot of problems adding a new payment method for a new billing account (also with Google Billing Support) - Long story short: I had to delete the private billing account and added a new company billing account.

Now I do not have that free trial banner with information anymore.

Rereading the conditions I'd say there should be no problem:

- 1.1 The Free Trial applies only to the use of the Services.
- 1.2 Only new Google Cloud Platform customers are eligible to participate in the Free Trial.
- 1.3 The Free Trial starts when Customer creates a billing account in the Google Cloud Console (“Free Trial Start Date”) and ends on the earlier of (i) the date that Customer’s fees for usage exceeds $300 or (ii) 12 months from the Free Trial Start Date.

So:

- How can I verify if I am still in the trial phase?
- If I got kicked out, what can I do to continue the trial phase?
- Is there anything else I'm probably missing?

Thank you for your time!

---

Sidenote (or better said my opinion):
Until now I didn't try more than the AppEngine.
With all the problems that I had with the payment method verification and the support (took 1 1/2 months), now loosing the free trial phase, I must say that I did not enjoy this whole bureaucracy in any way and am almost done with the "cloud hype", feeling to me like a "big giant buzzword bureaucracy monster" :'(.

Comment: Did you register with the same user/credit card/org the second time as you initially did in the first trial? If so then that's likely why you're no longer under a free trial, as GCP already had your info on record.

Comment: Oh you're right, that's my situation!
I guess that's the problem and I guess there will be no solution.
I will retry the billing support but I guess bureaucracy will prevent to continue my trial...

Comment: It was not possible to bring the trial to the new billing account.
However we did reactivate the old billing account and meanwhile our accountant has to deal with it.
The best I could get with with my error in the beginning.